# Show that this is a diffeomorphism

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, differential-geometry

I have a function $F:(0,2\pi) \times \mathbb{R}_{>0} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{>0}^2$
with $(\phi,r)\mapsto(r(\phi-\sin(\phi)),r(1-cos(\phi)))$ and want to show that this is a smooth(meaning $C^{\infty}$ ) diffeomorphism. actually, i have already shown that this is ja bijection, but it seems to be difficult to show that the inverse function is also arbitrarily often differentiable.

Comment: Try to use the inverse function theorem

Comment: Well, I do not know why the jacobi matrix will not become singular eventually, as the second derivative with respect to r is always zero?

Comment: Write down the Jacobian and see where it might be degenerate.

Comment: well i know how to do this for the first derivative, but i need to do this for the second, third, fourth and so on, right? unfortunately, i do not know how to do this.

Comment: @Lipschitz You don't have to. The inverse function theorem tells you that if the map is at least $C^1$ with nonvanishing Jacobian, then its inverse (which exists locally) is as smooth as the map itself. Basically, this comes from differentiating $F^{-1}\circ F=\mathrm{id}$ $k$ times using the chain rule, and then looking at the highest derivative of $F^{-1}$.

Comment: so i should have a look at the following determinant http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=det%28%28a-sin%28a%29%2Cr*%281-cos%28a%29%29%29%2C%281-cos%28a%29%2Cr*sin%28a%29%29%29 and since this is nonzero for all a and r in the given domain i have proved the smoothness, is this correct?

Comment: @Lipschitz The link is broken, but I think you have the right idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three things to check.

1. The map $F$ is $C^\infty$ smooth.
2. Its Jacobian is nowhere zero.
3. It is a bijection.

Once you are done with 1 and 2, the inverse function theorem applies and shows that the map is *locally* a $C^\infty$ diffeomorphism. But Part 3 is still necessary because you are asked to show it's a *global* diffeomorphism.